# ¿Cómo puedo descargar un archivo csv con angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, csv, blob

Estoy tratando de descargar un archivo de csv pero me sale este error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad"
Les muestro mis funciones:
La función getTransactionCsv manda a llamar al api.

```js
dowloandCsv(){
    let _ = this;
    let conditions = {
      "conditions":{
        "transaction_id": _.id,
        "date_from": _.dateFrom, //Optional field (AAAA-MM-DD)
        "date_until": _.dateUntil, //Optional field (AAAA-MM-DD)
        "points": _.points,
        "amount": _.amount,
        "account": _.account,
        "office": _.office,
        "reference": _.reference,
        "page_ini": "", // Optional field *
        "page_end": "", // Optional field *
        "export_file": true
      }
    }
    _.apiRequestService.getTransactionCsv(conditions).subscribe(data => _.getRequestFile(data)),
      error => console.log("Error"),
      () => console.info("OK");
  }

  getRequestFile(data: any){
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "text/csv" });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
    console.log(data);
    }
```

```html
<a class="btn backGray" (click)="dowloandCsv()">Descargar</a>
```

```js
//Este es mi service

getTransactionCsv(conditions){
    let _ = this;

    let header = new HttpHeaders();
    let other_header = header.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('tkAccess'));

    return _.http.post(_.apiURL + 'transaction/search', conditions, {headers: other_header})
  }
```

Comment: Has puesto el código de tu Controller, pero lo que necesitaría ver es el código de tu Service: el fallo es causado porque la petición AJAX espera una respuesta JSON (seguramente tengas el content-type `application/json` pero debería ser `text/csv`)

Comment: Listo ya añadi mi service, gracias

Comment: ¿El objeto http es un HttpClient o Http?

Answer (score 1):

Asumo que estás usando Angular4 o anterior y por lo tanto no estás usando HttpClient:

Tienes que decirle a Angular que no intente procesar la respuesta como JSON, diciéndole que es texto:

```
getTransactionCsv(conditions){
  let header = new HttpHeaders();
  header = header.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('tkAccess'));
  const opt = {
    headers: other_header
    responseType: ResponseContentType.Text
  };
  return this.http.post(_.apiURL + 'transaction/search', conditions, opt);
}
```

puedes importar este `enum` así:

```
import { ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: Aunque no tiene que ver con lo que se pregunta, considero que es importante resaltar que el token de acceso no debería ser almacenado en el local storage de una aplicación. ¿qué opinas al respecto?